# How to properly size image to support 1x, 2x, and 3x devices

Tags: ios, xcode

My app is similar to Facebook, but I have a targeted audience. My tab bar icons follow Apple specs for 1x, 2X, and 3x.  It just occurred to me that through out the app I set height and width for the primary image.

I've set constraints properly, I'm sure. But setting the height and width to a fixed size won't scale from an iPhone 6s to 6+.  Will it?

What is the proper way to set the size of an image?

Comment: To the person that down voted this question.  It's not too broad.  Providing icons in your app that are 1x, 2x, 3x is one thing.  How do you deal with an uploaded photo?  That is my question.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking... Are you setting an ImageView to, say, `300 x 300` (for a 6s) and you want to know how to get it to scale to, say, `320 x 320` for a 6+?

Comment: I have a UITableView that has self-sizing UITableViewCells I must specify a height for the UIImageView for the cell to properly size.  You must set the height constraint for every item in the cell for it to size properly (vertically).  If I (and I must) set the height of that image will the image appear properly on 6S and 6 Plus devices?

Comment: You don't have to set a "pixel" value for the height.... you can set the height by making it proportional to the width, for example. But it's still unclear. Do you want the image to stretch the full width of the table? 25% of the width? Do you want it to be 100-pts tall, and whatever width maintains proportion?

Comment: Did you try set lower priority for UIImageView height and width constrains? Decrease from prority 1000 to 250.

Comment: Image size has nothing to do with 1x 2x 3x. Tab bar icons are the same size on all devices (before iOS 11, that is).

Comment: "How do you deal with an uploaded photo? That is my question" No, it isn't. Your question talks about tab bar icons and 1x 2x 3x, and that's all it talks about.

Answer (score 0):

> How to properly size image to support 1x, 2x, and 3x devices

You're comparing apples and oranges. 1x, 2x, and 3x has nothing to do with size. It has to do with *resolution*. As long as you provide an image at 1x, 2x, and 3x, it will be the *same* size and look good on all devices.

Now you might want for other reasons to provide the image at *different* sizes for different *screen* sizes. But that has nothing to do with 1x, 2x, 3x; it is orthogonal to it.

> What is the proper way to set the size of an image?

You do *not* set the size of an image. An image *has* a size.